# Onclick activates on start then does nothing

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I am having this strange problem, where I am trying to create buttons then assigning a onclick event to them. The onclick function starts as soon as the page is loaded, then does nothing when I click it.

```
var walk    = require('walk');
var files   = [];

//Scan
var walker  = walk.walk('./src/scripts/plugins', { followLinks: false });
walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
    listPluginE(stat.name)
    next();
});

var walker  = walk.walk('./src/scripts/disabledplugins', { followLinks: false });
walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
    listPluginD(stat.name,"disabled")
    next();
});

function listPluginE(dir) {
    //Text
    var dir = arguments[0]
    var type = "enabled"
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var t = document.createTextNode(dir);
    para.className = type;
    para.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('enabledSpace').appendChild(para);
    //Disable
    var disable = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Disable");
    disable.className = "disable";
    disable.onclick = test()
    disable.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('enabledSpace').appendChild(disable);
    //Delete
    var delButton = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Delete");
    delButton.className = "del";
    delButton.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('enabledSpace').appendChild(delButton);
    }

function listPluginD(dir) {
    //Text
    var dir = arguments[0]
    var type = "disabled"
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var t = document.createTextNode(dir);
    para.className = type;
    para.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('disabledSpace').appendChild(para);
    //Enable
    var enable = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Enable");
    enable.className = "enable";
    enable.onclick = test()
    enable.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('disabledSpace').appendChild(enable);
    //Delete
    var delButton = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Delete");
    delButton.className = "del";
    delButton.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('disabledSpace').appendChild(delButton);
    }

function enablePlugin(name) {
    name = arguments[0]
    fs.rename("./src/scripts/disabledplugins/" + name,"./src/scripts/plugins/" + name)
    location.reload();
}
function disablePlugin(name) {
    name = arguments[0]
    fs.rename("./src/scripts/plugins/" + name,"./src/scripts/disabledplugins/" + name)
    location.reload();
}
function test() {
    console.log("test")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are **executing** the `test()` function rather than passing a reference to it.

You need to do this instead:

```
enable.onclick = test
```

**WHY:**

The JavaScript interpreter assigns whatever value is on the right to the variable on the left. In your case, what happened was that the interpreter executed the `test` function and assigned the return value (which for was undefined) to the `onclick` event handler.

**EDIT:** If you want to pass in `dir` into your `test` function: you will need to make a function wrapper like this:

```
enable.onclick = function () {
    test(dir);
}
```

Notice that the wrapper function is not executed (no `()`s). The `test` function will be executed `onclick`.

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem! But one problem. In the finished product, I will be using the disablePlugin(name) and enablePlugin(name) how would I use arguments?

Comment: @Minecheese, what variable do you intend to pass into those functions?

Comment: I planned on passing in dir

Answer (score 0):

@jsve's answer didn't quite work (Gives an undefined error) but it did give me an idea, which works. I put the scripts with arguments I wanted to execute in functions. Here is my final code.

```
var walk    = require('walk');
var files   = [];

//Scan
var walker  = walk.walk('./src/scripts/plugins', { followLinks: false });
walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
    listPluginE(stat.name)
    next();
});

var walker  = walk.walk('./src/scripts/disabledplugins', { followLinks: false });
walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
    listPluginD(stat.name,"disabled")
    next();
});

function listPluginE(dir) {
    //Text
    var dir = arguments[0]
    var type = "enabled"
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var t = document.createTextNode(dir);
    para.className = type;
    para.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('enabledSpace').appendChild(para);
    //Disable
    var disable = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Disable");
    disable.className = "disable";
    disable.onclick = function() { disablePlugin(dir); }
    disable.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('enabledSpace').appendChild(disable);
    //Delete
    var delButton = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Delete");
    delButton.className = "del";
    delButton.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('enabledSpace').appendChild(delButton);
    }

function listPluginD(dir) {
    //Text
    var dir = arguments[0]
    var type = "disabled"
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var t = document.createTextNode(dir);
    para.className = type;
    para.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('disabledSpace').appendChild(para);
    //Enable
    var enable = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Enable");
    enable.className = "enable";
    enable.onclick = function() { enablePlugin(dir); };
    enable.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('disabledSpace').appendChild(enable);
    //Delete
    var delButton = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Delete");
    delButton.className = "del";
    delButton.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('disabledSpace').appendChild(delButton);
    }


function enablePlugin(name) {
    name = arguments[0]
    fs.rename("./src/scripts/disabledplugins/" + name,"./src/scripts/plugins/" + name)
    location.reload();
}
function disablePlugin(name) {
    name = arguments[0]
    fs.rename("./src/scripts/plugins/" + name,"./src/scripts/disabledplugins/" + name)
    location.reload();
}
```